# Is a SATA splitter a thing?

Tags: hard-drive, sata

Is it possible to split the data plug of a SATA connection?  I have 2 hard drives and an optical drive I want to use simultaneously, but my computer only has 2 SATA connections.  I can power the extra hard drive from another PSU I have, so power isn't an issue.  The question is if its possible to split the data connection.

Comment: No splitting a SATA connection is not possible. There are SATA expansion boards that use PCIe and give you additional SATA ports (some have 10 or more connectors on a pretty small board).

Comment: Your question has an answer already. check this [link](http://superuser.com/questions/777570/is-there-a-sata-cable-which-can-connect-to-multiple-disks.)

Comment: There are such things as SATA port multipliers, but the more common Intel SATA controllers on motherboards don't support them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. What you *might* be able to do (check the documentation) is to connect a SATA RAID enclosure to your one SATA port, then configure the enclosure to "see" two separate volumes. Depending on the hardware, you could even get "hot-plug" capability thrown in.

I seem to remember a (Lindy?) gimmick I found on Amazon that basically did this, without even the enclosure - just a Y-cable with a box in the middle.

But very often this "trick" requires that you first **format both of your hard drives** to make them "known" to the enclosure. While this might sometimes be even more desirable (i.e. one can "see" a larger *single* volume, which might be preferred over two separate volumes)... in your case, it might *not*.